# Query - Select By Attribute

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, query, contour

I have contour data of 1 foot contours. How do I write a select by attribute query to only select 10 foot intervals. ie: 750, 760, 770, 780......

Than data range is between 10ft and 900ft, est. So I can't do and "equal to" expression in ArcGIS Pro.

I tried the expression MOD([ELEV], 10) = 0, but it failed.

This data covers Eagle Pass, TX.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose the field name with double quotes `""` because enclosing of the field name depends on the file type. You can refer to [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-04DAAB63-BCB9-4D25-8424-63DDA67DFDCB) If you are using File Geodatabase or shapefile, you need to use double quotes.

```
MOD("ELEV", 10) = 0
```

In the following shapefile example, double quotes is used and the expression works without a problem:

[image]

Comment: GENIUS! It worked. Walked into work this morning with a solution, THANK YOU.